# I need to be able to change the background color of li when selected with the mouse. using css only

Tags: user-interface, css, frontend

I have ul menu with li's no a:links and I need to be able to change the background color of li when selected with the mouse.

```
    <div id="dvMainNavMenu">
        <ul id="NavItem">
        <li>Nav Item</li> 
          <li>Nav Item</li>   
          <li>Nav Item</li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

#NavItem li  {background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; }
#NavItem li:hover {background-color: #ff8700;}
#NavItem li:focus {background-color: #ff8700;}
```

the focus is not working ;( can someone help me?

Comment: Selected as in clicked? I'm afraid :focus/:active don't work like that in newer Browsers anymore.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ezTpf/

Comment: @j08691: Tested on what browser? IE9, Latests FF/Chrome don't work that way...

Comment: @BradChristie - Works for me in Chrome and FF. And IE8.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the question. Thought he just needed the hover.

Comment: @j08691: FF 11.0, Chrome 17.0.963.78, IE 9.0.8112.16421--even Safari 5.1 (7534.50) all don't work. -- EDIT: Ahh, I see the confusion now.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, so long as you realise that a non-interactive element (interactive elements are those like `input`, `select`, `a`...) cannot be focused. It *can* respond to the `:active` pseudo-class but that won't persist once the mouse is released (and will be overridden by the default action of selection if the mouse is moved):

```
#NavItem li  {background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; }
#NavItem li:hover {background-color: #ff8700;}
#NavItem li:active {background-color: #f00;}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezTpf/3/).

It's important to remember that CSS is used for presentation. JavaScript is (and potentially other languages, such as [dart](/questions/tagged/dart) are) used for functionality/behaviour/interaction layers on top of the content provided by the HTML.

Using JavaScript *isn't* a form of 'cheating.'

Answer (score 1):

What if you used the [:target pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo) in combination with links.  The negative is that you could only have one highlighted at a time.  As a very rough demo, [check out this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfCLs/) or view the HTML/CSS below.

```
    <div id="dvMainNavMenu">
      <ul id="NavItem">
        <li><a href="#item1" id="item1">Nav Item</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#item2" id="item2">Nav Item</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#item3" id="item3">Nav Item</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>

#NavItem li  {background-color: transparent; text-decoration: none; }
#NavItem li:hover {background-color: #ff8700;}
#NavItem li:focus {background-color: #ff8700;}
#NavItem li a { display:block; }
#NavItem li a:target { background-color:black; }
```

​
This would obviously work in only specific scenarios, so it may or may not fit with what you are trying to do and [it's not universal browser support (IE9 and up)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3atarget).

Comment: $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("li").css("backgroundColor", "");
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#ff8700'
    }, 'fast');});
            
   
});

Answer (score 0):

Elements that aren't input or "focus-worthy" [©/™/etc.] aren't going to acknowledge the `:focus`, `:active`, etc. pseudo-classes that CSS has to offer. You could probably hack it using an anchor (`<a>`) but now you're left with providing a `href` target and, once again, without javascript intervention you'll either be scrolling the window to a named anchor/matching ID or trying to hack around any other effects using an `<a>` may have. And without a `href` you're losing a lot of of inherent abilities.

With that said, a little javascript can do exactly what you're after while still being (relatively) light weight. And, worst-case scenario, a browser that's either unsupportive of javascript or disables it will fall-back to only have the `:hover` ability.

With that, here's the javascript alternative:

Create a class:

```
#NavItem .active { background-color: #FF8700; }
```

Then:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('NavItem');
if (ul){
    var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++){
        li[i].onclick = function(e){
            var re = /\b(active)\b/;
            if (this.className.test(re)){
                this.className = this.className.replace(re,'').replace(/^\s+$/,'');
            }else{
                this.className += ' active';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, the nice jQuery method:

```
$('#NavItem li').click(function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: @DavidThomas: You read my comment about it not being possible, right? Which would then make this a [functioning] alternative.

Comment: No, I hadn't. But, while you're right that this is certainly a (good) alternative, you should probably explain why you're posting a JavaScript answer to a CSS-only question. I wasn't going to down-vote, ...as brusque as I might've seemed I really was trying to help. Sorry about my tone, if it seemed abrupt. =/

Comment: $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings("li").css("backgroundColor", "");
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#ff8700'
    }, 'fast');});
            
   
});

Comment: @DavidThomas: Dually noted and corrections/disclaimer added. My apologies for the abrasive response back, but unfortunately tone doesn't convey well on the internet. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. Default color that changes when I the mouse its over and changes again when it is selected, using just CSS.

```
nav {background-color: #253575; height: 50px; width: 100%; position: fixed; margin-top: 100px;}
   #contenidonav {margin-left: -33px;}
   nav a {text-decoration: none; color: #B5C4E3; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;}
            nav a:focus {color: #FF9000; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 15px;}

   nav li {display: inline; margin-right: 2px; color: #B5C4E3; background-color: #253791; padding-top: 8px; padding-bottom: 8px; border-radius: 4px;}
            nav li:hover {background-color: #31479B;}
            nav li:focus {background-color: #ffffff; width:100%;}
```